# what "master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives" returns

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I am trying to run the below command(in a remote server) in sql server 2008 r2 to get free disc space of all base, log, data and backup drive.

```
master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives
```

instead i am getting only one output

```
drive   MB free

C   146022
```

how can i get all the drive info.

Answer (score 0):

If any network drives are mapped on server then those will not be shown through this procedure.

Comment: Thanks Ranjit for reply.
Is there any way to see all the mapped and physical drive as well along with their type(base, log, backup etc)